# apply jquery function to multiple divs

Tags: jquery, overlay

I need to apply this little jquery function:

```
    $(function(){
        $('.trigger').click(function(){
            $('.img-popup').fadeIn(500);
            $('.overlay').fadeIn(500);
        });
        $('.overlay').click(function(){
            $('.img-popup').fadeOut(500);
            $('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
        });
    });
```

to a series of divs:

```
<td class="result" >
    <div class="trigger"><b>Show image 1</b></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="img-popup">
        <img src="imageurl-1">
    </div>
</td>
...
<td class="result" >
    <div class="trigger"><b>Show image 2</b></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="img-popup">
        <img src="imageurl-2">
    </div>
</td>
```

What could be the best approach?

I sense I should use an .each() somewhere, but how can I get the related div with .overlay class and related .img-popup to show?

Or maybe I could just change the `$('.trigger').click(function()` and let it take only the nearest .img-popup div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to use the $(this) selector when you loop through each div?

Comment: Given your current code, you just need to update the `$('.img-popup')` and `$('.overlay')` to use `$(this).parent()` before them. For example, `$(this).parent().find('.overlay')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to reference to the right img:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.img-popup').fadeIn(500);
   $(this).siblings('.overlay').fadeIn(500);
}
$(".overlay").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.img-popup').fadeOut(500);
   $(this).siblings('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop with `each()`, just use `$(this)` for the clicked button and parent selector with jQuery to find `.img-popup` and `.overlay`

```
$(function(){
    $('.trigger').click(function(){
        var element = $(this), parent = element.parent(".result"),
            img_popup = parent.find('.img-popup'), 
            overlay = parent.find('.overlay');
        img_popup.fadeIn(500);
        overlay.fadeIn(500);
    });
    $('.overlay').click(function(){
        var element = $(this), parent = element.parent(".result"),
            img_popup = parent.find('.img-popup');
        img_popup.fadeOut(500);
        element.fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given code, you could just use `siblings()`
So inside of the click handlers use these to target

```
$(this).siblings('.img-popup');
$(this).siblings('.overlay');
```

if your html gets more complicated, you can use `.closest()` to get the result parent, like so

```
var $result = $(this).closest('.result');
$result.find('.img-popup');
$result.find('.overlay');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.overlay').eq(0).fadeIn(500).parent().children('.img-popup').eq(0).fadeIn(500);
});

$('.overlay').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500).parent().children('.img-popup').eq(0).fadeOut(500);
});
```